# Отправка AJAX запроса с помощью ссылки в Yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2

Нужно отправить запрос с помощью ссылки, что-то вроде такого:

```
<a href="#" class="messages_close">
    <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
</a>
```

Может быть что-то вроде этого?

```
<?php
$js = <<<JS
$(".messages_close").click(function () {
    var id = 8;
    $.ajax({
        url: "'.\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['messages/exclude','id'=>8]).'",
        type: "get",
        data: "id="+this.id,
        success: function(){
            alert('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR :: ' +  'id=' + this.id);
        }
    });
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
```

Это вообще возможно? Я слабо разбираюсь в JS и AJAX, нужен пример.